# Removing ^M From File Generated on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, text-files

Alright, I'm attempting to remove these pesky ^M characters that pop up when I compile and run my program on Linux.

I've attempted running

```
dos2unix filename
```

on the file, and the ^M's remain. I've also made sure that anytime I am opening the file, I am opening with

```
ios::binary
```

Is there some way to remove the M's? Even a system call would work that I could call within my code would be fine as well, something like

```
std::system("Remove M's Command");
```

Any feedback would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to open without ios::binary to just let it use text mode?

Comment: What file generated on linux? Linux doesn't normally put `^M`s unless you ask it to.

Comment: Joachim, yes I tried without ios::binary, still the same trouble. Mike, if it helps, the cpp file used was transferred from a Windows machine. dos2unix was run on this before hand however.

Comment: Let me guess - using a Windows editor and compiling under Linux. Fix the editor! (Two large Gin and Tonics usually does the trick!)

Comment: @EdHeal, would sound like that if we didn't talk about opening file. But it says "files generated on linux", anyway...

Comment: Sorry - Was distracted. Why not change the code to ignore them?

Comment: I don't think `dos2unix` modifies files in place. It's a filter, and the fixed file goes to stdout. You'd need to do something like `dos2unix foo > bar` then if `bar` looks ok, `mv bar foo`.

Comment: They're appearing in a file you're writing with your program?  Where does the file content come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your C++ program is already structured like this:

```
std::string str;
std::ifstream inputFile("file.txt", ios::binary);
while (std::getline(inputFile, str)) {
  // parse str and operate on the results
}
```

Then you can easily change it to:

```
std::string str;
std::ifstream inputFile("file.txt", ios::binary);
while(std::getline(inputFile, str)) {
  str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\r'), str.end());
  // parse str and operate on the results.
}
```

Comment: Ran this, the ^M's still remain in the file. Is there perhaps a command that will just go through the file and remove any ^M's?

Comment: Yes, there are many. Among them are: use `dos2unix` correctly, use the Perl script mentioned in another answer, `sed s/\r//g`, `tr -d '\r'`.

Comment: Thanks Rob, actually the one that did the trick was tr -d '\b\r' <original_file_name> new_file_name. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

A number of tools will do it with a regular expression.  For example, perl can edit the file in place:

```
# perl -i -p -e 's/\r//g' FILENAME
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what `ios::binary` is, but it seems to me like the key.
It sounds related to Apple systems, and they use the CR (^M) character instead of LF (while Windows uses both). So if you have only CR, not CR-LF, then dos2unix won't work.

So why not just remove `ios::binary` (as @Joachim-Isaksson suggested)?

Comment: As I said, I have already tried it without ios::binary and simply put it in to see if it would fix the situation, so that is not the culprit. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: It specifies to open the file in binary mode: http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs2604/fall02/binio.html#open